# Quoting word list

Tags: capitalization, quotation-marks

I think this is probably a basic question, but I just cannot seem to decide how to correctly punctuate this passage:

> There is a part of the evaluation where the nurse goes through the words, "Foot, blue, and dog." Five minutes later the patient could not recall "Blue" or "Dog."

Have I quoted these words correctly, or should not they not have quotes at all?

Also would you capitalize the first letter inside the quotes?

Comment: Compare your final **could not recall "Blue" or "Dog."** (correct except the period should be *outside* the quote marks), with the preceding **goes through the words, "Foot, blue, and dog."** Punctuation marks, and the words "**and**" and "**or**", are not included within the list of things (words such as "foot" and "blue") which the patient can't remember.

Comment: *... goes through the words, "Foot," "blue," and "dog."* Like in the second sentence:  *... could not recall "Blue" or "Dog."*

Comment: _"foot, blue," and "dog"_ will do. It's not necessary to use extra quotes to keep a space out of the quotation. Space is, um .., silent.

Answer (score 1):

I find it more pragmatic to use single-quotes to demarcate words that are meant to be read as is, rather than interpreted within the context of the sentence in which they are contained. It's a kind of "poor man's italics". I would rewrite your example as follows:

> There is a part of the evaluation where the nurse goes through the words 'foot', 'blue', and 'dog'. Fives minutes later, the patient could not recall 'blue' or 'dog'.

Note that I place the full-stop ( period ) outside the single quotes, because it is part of the sentence, not the demarcated word. If you have mark-up capabilities available, then it makes more sense to dispense with delimiter marks altogether, like so:

> There is a part of the evaluation where the nurse goes through the words *foot*, *blue*, and *dog*. Fives minutes later, the patient could not recall *blue* or *dog*.